# Как в ответ на GET / POST запрос получить ответ в формате JSON?

Tags: c#, http

Нужно отправить из приложения `WinForms` `GET`-запрос (в перспективе, возможно и `POST`) к серверу и получить объект по ответу в формате `JSON`. Естественно, известно что сервер может отвечать в формате `JSON`.

Запросы примерно в таком виде:

```
http://server.ru/service.page/subservice/eventservice?param=valueparam
```

Как сформировать `JSON`, нашел:

```
JavaScriptSerializer jsonSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
String result = jsonSerializer.Serialize(new { json_v1 = 1, json_v2 = "2222" });
```

И получить из `JSON` объект, тоже понятно:

```
TypeObj obj = jsonSerializer.Deserialize<TypeObj>(result);
```

Но как послать сам запрос и считать ответ - увы, не знаю. Нашел несколько примеров, но объем кода удручает ( 30-50 строк только на запрос - это слишком).
Кто сталкивался или у кого есть идеи - прошу, подскажите.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В общем случае послать запрос и считать ответ можно одной строкой:

```
string responsetext = new StreamReader(HttpWebRequest.Create("УРЛ вашего сервиса").GetResponse().GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
```

Или так:

```
string responsetext = new WebClient().DownloadString("УРЛ вашего сервиса");
```

Но это всё синхронно, без авторизации и проверки ошибок.

Асинхронно можно вот так:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();     
wc.DownloadStringCompleted += 
    delegate(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e) 
    {
        string responsetext = e.Result;
    };
wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("URL вашего сервиса"));
```

Если надо методом POST, то тогда вот так:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.UploadDataCompleted += 
    delegate(object sender, UploadDataCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        string responsetext = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.Result);
    };
wc.UploadDataAsync(new Uri("URL вашего сервиса"), Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("То что вы будете отправлять POSTом"));
```

Подробная информация:  [WebClient Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.webclient.aspx)